# Bash trap unset from function

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Namely, http://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Error_handling#Set_ERR_trap_to_exit

Why is it necessary to `set -o errtrace` to make trap set/unset from a function call work?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function trapit {
    echo 'trapped in a box'
}

function setTrap {
    trap 'trapit' ERR
}

function unsetTrap {
    trap - ERR
}

function foo_init {
    fooOldErrtrace=$(set +o | grep errtrace)
    set -o errtrace
    trap 'echo trapped' ERR   # Set ERR trap
}

function foo_deinit {
    trap - ERR                # Reset ERR trap
    eval $fooOldErrtrace      # Restore `errtrace' setting
    unset fooOldErrtrace      # Delete global variable
}

# foo_init
setTrap
echo 'set'
false

echo 'unset'
#foo_deinit
unsetTrap
false
```

Answer (score 0):

According to man bash(5) functions not inherits ERR trap without the errtrace flag turned on. I dont know why ERR trap cant be inherited by default, but... it is so for now :)

You can test this behaviour with my sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
trapit ()  {
 echo 'some error trapped'
}

doerr1 () {
 echo 'I am the first err generator and i return error status to the callee'
 return 1
}

doerr2 () {
 echo 'I am the second err generator and i produce an error inside my code'
 fgrep a /etc/motttd
 return 0
}

[[ $1 ]] && set -o errtrace

trap trapit ERR

doerr1

doerr2

echo 'We will produce an exception in the main program...'
cat /etc/ftab | fgrep a

echo 'OK, thats done, you see it :)'
```

If you pass any parameter to this script, errtrace flag will be turned on and you will see that exception was "catched" when doerr2 tried to do something awful.

Comment: What bothers me is that traps set from a function are set on the global scope, but can't be unset in the same way. You can set something globally, but cannot unset it in the same way. I wonder why.